# Set defaultTextAttributes using User Defined Runtime Attributes?

Tags: ios, xcode

Say you are setting

```
 field
      .defaultTextAttributes
      .updateValue(20.0, forKey: NSAttributedStringKey.kern.rawValue)
```

(BTW you do that to space out text, like *t h i s*.)

in fact, is there a way to set that using User Defined Runtime Attributes,

right on the storyboard in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. User Defined Runtime Attributes works only where key-value coding would work, with a limited range of value types. A moment's thought will reveal that your code can't be expressed in that way.

You could, however, subclass to define a custom property and set it to 20 in User Defined Runtime Attributes, and respond with a setter observer to run the code you've shown. That way, different fields can have different kern values depending on a setting in the storyboard.

(If you're going to do that, you might as well make this property IBInspectable; IBInspectable effectively *is* User Defined Runtime Attributes, with a different interface.)

Comment: Great stuff.  Does this mean that `.defaultTextAttributes` is not key-value compliant??  (Could they in the future "make that one" key value compliant, or am I just not understanding something?)

Comment: Try what I said. Try to rewrite your code using `set(_:forKey:)` using only a value type of Boolean, NSNumber, NSString, CGPoint, CGSize, CGRect, NSRange, or UIColor. Can you do it?

Comment: Sorry if my further question wasn't clear.  (Yes, I'm familiar with how to "make your own" property to use in U.D.R.A, and of course using IBInspectable.)  Cheers again